# Chimera Security Review not finding anti-abuse token for Heroku NodeJs application

Tags: appexchange, security-review, node.js, chimera-security-scanner

I'm trying to review a Nodejs web application as part of an SF app exchange registration - using Chimera. First hurdle is the review keeps coming back unable to verify it's my app. I've uploaded ChimeraToken.txt to the root folder of the Nodejs app (same folder as app.js). Not sure if this really is the root folder that Chimera can access?

Anyone got experience with Nodejs and Chimera?

Answer (score 1):

So, this doesn't exactly answer the question, but i added tokens to *public*, *app* and *views* folders and it worked.

**Update:**

Adding the token to the Nodejs static root folder worked. In my case the was `/app` folder; as indicated:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
```

Comment: It would be good to expand this towards an answer others could follow.